# Conditional Probability In Markov Chains

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Suppose we have a Matrix with transition probabilities:

\begin{bmatrix}
p_{00} & p_{01} & p_{02}\\
p_{10} & p_{11} & p_{12}\\
p_{20} & p_{21} & p_{22}
\end{bmatrix}

I need to calculate: $a)P[X(2) = 0|X(1) = 2, X(0) = 1]$

**My thoughts:**

$ P[X(2) = 0|X(1) = 2, X(0) = 1] = P[X(2) = 0|X(1) = 2]$ using Markov property.

$P[X(2) = 0|X(1) = 2]  = \frac{P[X(2) = 0 \cap X(1) = 2]}{P[X(1) = 2]}$

Here I am stuck and don't know how to proceed. I suppose, that probability of $P[X(2) = 0 \cap X(1) = 2]$ is just $p_{20}$, because we move from state 2 to state 1 and we don't consider what happened in time 0 because if Markov property. But how do we calculate $P[X(1) = 2]$? Should we take into account all states or just the information from $ P[X(2) = 0|X(1) = 2, X(0) = 1]$(starting point is state 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$P([X(2)=0|X(1)=2)=P([X(1)=0|X(0)=2)=p_{20}$$

Note that $p_{20}$ is a conditional probability.